# Data structure for D3 pie charts

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, pie-chart

I am currently taking my first steps in D3 data visualisation. So far, the D3 tutorials have helped me a lot. The pie chart tutorial http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235 though does not further explain the necessary data structure for pie charts.

My data is more complex than the label/value structure of the example. I have the annual total import data and import data of a specific good stored in JSON:

```
var data = [{"year":"2001","total_import":"100000","import_specific_good":"25000"},{"year":"2002",...}];
```

If I understand the tutorial correctly pie() iterates over the SAME entry of each DIFFERENT object.

What if I need specific DIFFERENT values of the SAME object?

I am not interested in a pie showing all annual total imports as portions, but the annual import of a specific good as a portion of the annual total import. My values would be 1. (total_import - import_specific_good) and 2. import_specific_good.

Is my proposed data structure correct for what I want to do? Or do I have to restructure everything so that the values for every year are stored in a separate variable?

```
var data_2001 = [{"label":"Total Import","value":"100000"},{"label":"Import of Specific Good","value":"25000"}];

var data_2002 = [{"label": ...}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a specific data structure -- you can (and will need to anyway) modify the example so you can use anything you like! So you can use your first JSON just fine. As you have only 2 values to show, you could simply construct the structure to pass to `.data()` on the fly.

```
// for pie chart
...data([json[index].total_import - json[index].import_specific_good,
         json[index].import_specific_good])...
...
// similarly for the labels
```

I would advise to store the numbers as numbers (e.g. without quotes) in your JSON though -- otherwise you'll have to convert them to numbers in Javascript.

Comment: This makes sense to me concerning the data() function. But what about `var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return WHAT COMES HERE?; });`? What do I do with the pie() function? PS: Thanks for the hint about string/integer.

Comment: If you call `pie()` with the data as above (i.e. the actual numbers), you don't need to specify `.value()`.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Since I have a lot of data, I can now iterate over my original json and create a pie chart for each year. Very convenient!

Comment: Just for comprehension: all values I provide to pie() will be added up and scaled to 100%/360 degress, right? That means the values within pie() represent my input domain while the 360 degrees represent my output range. Did I get this correctly?

Comment: Yes. It's basically a convenience function that provides, among other things, this.