# Trying to draw a d3 pie chart from json data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I am trying to generate a d3 pie chart from the following json data.

`{"data":[
    {"Success":3412,
    "Pending":2107}
]}`

This data is retrieved from an sql table. Success and Pending are the column headers in the sql table. The following is the code I am trying to use to generate the piechart.

```
var width = 360;
var height = 360;
var outradius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var inradius = outradius / 1.25;

var color = d3.scale.category20b();

var svg = d3.select('#Chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(outradius)
  .innerRadius(inradius);
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function (d, i) { return d.data.Success; })
  .sort(null);
var path = svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(dataset.data))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
      return color(d.data.Pending);
  });
```

I have created the d3 pie chart for tables where I am plotting the values of a certain column. But here I need to plot the values from two columns in a single piechart to compare with each other.

The above code will compare the values of all "Success" keys and fill the different colours based on the "Pending" key. But I have just one Success and Pending Key:value pair in the json and I need to compare them in piechart.

Is there any way achieve this?

I read this thread: [Data structure for D3 pie charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200095/data-structure-for-d3-pie-charts?rq=1)

But I am not sure how to pass the data to the pie. Can you edit my code snippet and show me? I am very new to web programming even though I have worked in java before.

Kind regards

Comment: So you want to show Success and pending on one pie chart ?

Comment: try to look this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22375778/4354249

Comment: @Farside I don't want to use highcharts. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you need to change your data as you only have one element in your dataset with `success` and `pending`. To compare both you need two sets of data like so :

```
var dataset = {
  "data": [{
    "Name": "Success",
    "Value": 3412
  }, {
    "Name": "Pending",
    "Value": 2107
  }]
}
```

Notice I have reformatted the code so you have `Name` and `Value`. This is so you can use the value for the size of the arc and the name as the colour/text.

To alter your data use this function :

```
var data = {
  "data": [{
    "Success": 3412,
    "Pending": 2107
  }]
}

var newData = [];
for (var key in data.data[0]) {
  console.log(key)
  var thisData = {
    "Name": key,
    "Value": data.data[0][key]
  }
  newData.push(thisData)
}

console.log(newData)
```

This goes through your data and creates new data that can be read by the D3.pie :)

Updated code :

```js
var data = {
  "data": [{
    "Success": 3412,
    "Pending": 2107
  }]
}

var newData = [];
for (var key in data.data[0]) {
 // console.log(key)
  var thisData = {
    "Name": key,
    "Value": data.data[0][key]
  }
  newData.push(thisData)
}


var width = 360;
var height = 360;
var outradius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var inradius = outradius / 1.25;

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var svg = d3.select('#Chart')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (width / 2) + ',' + (height / 2) + ')');
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(outradius)
  .innerRadius(inradius);
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d, i) {
    console.log(d)
    return d.Value;
  })
  .sort(null);
var path = svg.selectAll('path')
  .data(pie(newData))
  .enter()
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return color(d.data.Name);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='Chart'>

</div>
```

Comment: If this isnt what you want, please elaborate

Comment: Thank you thisOneguy. But how can I change the json in your format? Is there any javascript function to do that?